# Add UITextField to Navigation Controller's Toolbar as a Bar Button Item through stroryboard

Tags: ios5, uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, xcode-storyboard

I can do this programmatically but I don't prefer it that way. There's got to be some work-around for this. This is what my initial screen looks like:

[image: Initial Screen]

To the toolbar, I dragged on a Bar Button Item and it fell into its proper place. Then i need a Text Field beside that. I dragged that from the library and dropped it beside the Bar Button item, and this is what I get:

[image: What I get]

What am I missing here?